# Error in database does not see column OS error - 11:Try again

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I ran into such a problem, at the beginning of creating the application I made a database, then I needed to refer to it and I get the error "no CollectionId column", changing the version of the database did not help. Please let me know what could be the problem Thank you in advance

DB

```
public static String TABLE_NAME = "CollectionPhoto";
    public static String COLLECTION_ID = "CollectionId";
    public static String FILE_NAME = "FileName";
    public static String FILE_NAME_SAMPLE = "FileNameSample";
    public static String DESCRIPTION = "Description";

public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("create table " + CollectionPhotoTable.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + "_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + CollectionPhotoTable.COLLECTION_ID + " text,"
                + CollectionPhotoTable.DESCRIPTION + " text,"
                + CollectionPhotoTable.FILE_NAME + " text,"
                + CollectionPhotoTable.FILE_NAME_SAMPLE + " text);"
```

Location of error

```
public Cursor cursor(String _collectionId) {
        return GlobalVars.db.rawQuery("select * from CollectionPhoto where CollectionId = ? ", new String[]{_collectionId});
    }
```

DBHelper

```
void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    CollectionPhotoTable.createTable(db);
    }
 static void deleteTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists CollectionPhoto");
        db.endTransaction();
    }
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        createTables(db);

    }
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        deleteTables(db);
        createTables(db);
    }
```

ERROR

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: CollectionId (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from CollectionPhoto where CollectionId = ?, (OS error - 11:Try again)
```